# QT bluetooth btchat tablet

Tags: android, qt, bluetooth

I've got a problem with the qt example btchat.
After opening the program on my tablet and clicking on connect it takes a few seconds and then the program crashes.

This is what qtcreator says:

```
W/BluetoothAdapter(19975): getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
D/BluetoothAdapter(19975): startLeScan(): null
W/libbtchat.so(19975): (null):0 ((null)): qt.bluetooth.android: Cannot start BTLE device scanner
F/libc    (19975): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x700081 in tid 20004 (QtThread)
I/DEBUG   (  133): pid: 19975, tid: 20004, name: QtThread  >>> org.qtproject.example.btchat <<<

I/Zygote  (  141): Process 19975 exited due to signal (11)

E/lowmemorykiller(  126): Error opening /proc/19975/oom_score_adj; errno=2

I/ActivityManager(  502): Process org.qtproject.example.btchat (pid 19975) has died
```

What happend here?
Similar things happen with btscanner. There I can see some bluetooth devices but after clicking on one of them the program stops working properly

```
W/libbtscanner.so(12880): (null):0 ((null)): qt.bluetooth.android: Cannot retrieve SDP UUIDs for "" ( "00:1A:7D:DA:71:13" )
```

It looks like the bluetooth stack changed since android 4.2 and now it doesnt work properly.
I can get a connection by using my pc (ubuntu) as a client and my tablet (android 5.0.2) as server.
When I use the tablet as a client it crashes.
Does anybody have a solution for qt?

Answer (score 0):

as idea:
if you are on android 6.0.1 check permissions.
You needs ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permissions

Comment: hi, im using android 5.0.2, he same problem appears with android 4.4.2 (i think).